# How would one say "Every once and a while"?

Tags: translation

As in "Every once and a while, I like to listen to Radiohead"

Answer (score 4):

Here are some possible translations (supposing you mean "every once **in** a while"): de tempo al tempo, fojfoje, iam-tiam.

Examples from [Tekstaro](http://www.tekstaro.com/):

> Fojfoje ŝi kaŭris ĉe la malsupraj librobretoj.
>
> Estis humide kaj malvarme, kaj iam-tiam ekpluvis.
>
> Inter la arboj, de tempo al tempo glitis ombro de ama paro.

Here's how I would translate your sentence:

> `Every once in a while, I like to listen to Radiohead.`
>
> De tempo al tempo mi ŝatas aŭskulti Radiohead.

According to [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/propraj_nomoj/ne-esperantigitaj.html#i-u5g) non-Esperantized names can appear without the O-ending or the N-ending.

Answer (score 4):

Your best choice would be ***de tempo al tempo*** - literally, from time to time.

***Foje***, ***kelkfoje***, and ***fojfoje*** are options. The first two mean "at times" and *fojfoje* means "on rare occasions".

My advice would be to avoid using *iam-tiam*. It's not a common expression. It doesn't seem to follow logically from the meaning of the words. Finally, although it is found in the Tekstaro, there are only a few authors who use it - and those that do seem to use it a lot. My hunch is that it's a literal translation of a Russian expression